# configure htaccess to grab GET and not directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url like this:

`www.mydomain.com/index.php?param1=first&param2=second&param3=thirth`

and I want to rewrite it to :

`www.mydomain.com/first/second/third`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Problem is, that I am getting error 404 (I think that server is looking for directory /first/second/third instead of letting index.php in root dir to GET parameters from URL). Am I wrong? Or how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect actually. You're using 3 back-reference vales in target but only 2 values are being captured.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA,L]
```